# Issue with escaped antislash before an escaped square bracket in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, backslash

I am having troubles with regex matching, when I have an antislash escaped before an escaped square bracket

```
import re

def test_regex(test_number, regex_to_test, string_to_test):
    if re.match(regex_to_test, string_to_test) is None:
        print("Test #{0} FAILED ! Returned value was None".format(test_number))
    else:
        print("Test #{0} OK".format(test_number))

#              REGEX APPLIED   STRING        REAL STRING
test_regex(0, "\\\{\\\}",     "\\{\\}")     # \{\}
test_regex(1, "\\\{\\\\\\\}", "\\{\\\}")    # \{\} or :\{\\} ???
test_regex(2, "\\\{\\\\\\\}", "\\{\\\\}")   # \{\\}
# Now we replace in test '{' and '}' respectively by '[' and ']'
test_regex(3, "\\\[\\\]",     "\\[\\]")     # \[\]
test_regex(4, "\\\[\\\\\\\]", "\\[\\\]")    # \[\] or :\[\\] ???
test_regex(5, "\\\[\\\\\\\]", "\\[\\\\]")   # \[\\]
# Extra incomprehensible
test_regex(6, "\\\{\\\}",     "\{\}")       # {}
test_regex(7, "\\\\{\\\\}",   "\{\}")       # {}
# Now we replace in test '{' and '}' respectively by '[' and ']'
test_regex(8, "\\\[\\\]",     "\[\]")       # []
test_regex(9, "\\\\[\\\\]",   "\[\]")       # []
```

Output:

```
Test #0 OK
Test #1 OK
Test #2 OK
Test #3 FAILED ! Returned value was None
Test #4 FAILED ! Returned value was None
Test #5 FAILED ! Returned value was None
Test #6 OK
Test #7 OK
Test #8 FAILED ! Returned value was None
Test #9 FAILED ! Returned value was None
```

Why switching from '{' and '}' to '[' and ']' change everything ?

How can I edit my regex to make tests #3 and #4 work as '{' and '}'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, in a simple string, a double backslash is interpreted as a single.

You should try to use the "r" letter before string in parameters, and it makes python interpreter, store it as a raw string, for example:

```
test_regex(3, r"\\\[\\\]",     "\\[\\]")
```

Output:

```
Test #3 OK
```